# where exactly to do array operations in react when it has to happen without firing any event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to render an array in my react.However this does not involve firing of any event say onclick. Earlier,I had been doing all these operations inside render this way

```
render(){
   let arr=[];
   for(let i=0;i<10;i++){
      arr.push('jamie');
   };
   return(
      <div> 
       {arr}
      </div>
   )
}
```

My concern is if this is good enough because every time rendering happens all this calculation will happen which may make things go slow .What are better solutions ?

Comment: This is not good I guess. Because on every `render()` it will:


1) create array
2) loop through array 10 times


it will increase space and time complexities.

Comment: extract your array functionality to separate function and use it in render like this.someFunc() , other option is componentDidMount()

Answer (score 1):

Put it in the constructor, that way, it only run once

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.arr=[];
  this.getArrayResult(10);
  this.state = {
   myState: this.arr
  }

}

getArrayResult(index){
 for(let i=0;i<index;i++){
         this.arr.push('jamie');
      };

}


render(){

   return(
      <div> 
       {this.arr}
       //or using the state
       {this.state.myState}
      </div>
   )
}
```

Comment: Hey ,I also need to update the state with these arrays by passing the index to a function

Comment: I've edited the code, is that what you are expecting?

Answer (score 0):

A functional solution would be to use memoization:

```
import memoize from "memoize-one";
const createArray = (x) => { /* your code */ };
const memoCreateArray = memoize(createArray);
const Component = ({x}) => {
   const arr = memoCreateArray(x);
   return <div>{arr}</div>;
};
```

A more "traditional" solution would store the computed value in the React component's state and update it using `getDerivedStateFromProps` or just reading it from the props but using a `PureComponent` to avoid calling `render()`. But those solutions are not recommended and have various pitfalls. Read https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#what-about-memoization for more information.

Answer (score 0):

try following:

```
this.state{myarr: []}
someFunc = () => {
  let arr=[];
  for(let i=0;i<10;i++)
    arr.push('jamie');
  this.setState({myarr: arr})

}

render(){
 return(
    <div> 
       this.state.myarr
    </div>
 )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do your array functions in componentDidMount life cycle hook of react-native